# Hojas en Macros Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Tengo un problemas, espero que me podáis ayudar. Tengo una macro que me recoger la información de una hoja, en un libro, y me la lleva a otra hoja, de otro libro.
Cada hoja de origen se recore con un un bucle. Hasta aquí bien, el problema está al darme cuenta que las hojas de origen no tiene el mismo nombre. Por ejemplo: Unas se llaman "HE 1" y otras "HE1".
¿Como puedo hacer para que coja los datos teniendo en cuenta este incoveniente?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente un bucle `For...Next` que recorra todas las hojas de tu libro.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet 'variable para la hoja de cálculo

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets 'iniciamos bucle que recorrerá todas las hojas del libro
    WS.Activate
    'resto de tu código.
    'Se ejecutará 1 vez por cada hoja de tu Libro

Next WS
```

Espero que puedas adaptarlo a tus necesidades

Comment: Muchas gracias. Problema resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el formato:

```
Dim ultlinea As Long
Dim rango As Variant
Dim cont As Long

ultlinea = Sheets("Prueba").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rango = Sheets("Factor").Range("A4:G7485")

For cont = 2 To ultlinea
id = Sheets("Prueba").Cells(cont, 1)
'resto de tu código

Next cont
```

Comment: Según entendí, no sabe el nombre de la hoja, y en la solución que estás proponiendo tiene que saberlo... Igualmente, sería bueno que incluyas un descripción de tu código y cómo es que solucionaría la pregunta